How to find an equation to calculate commissions
I need to quickly calculate prices based on the commission I will be getting. Each sale pays commission based on 2 values: First, the commission on the base price is 8%. Anything over the base price of the item is paid at 40%. However, you will never earn more than 24% of the entire sale price.
For instance, if the base price is $5000, and the item is sold for 7000$, then you would receive 5000*.08 or $400 and then 2000$ * .4 or $800 for a total commission of $1200.  I basically need to know what I should be charging based on a commission value; for instance, If I want to make $1000, and the base price is 3000$, then I would need to charge 1900 over the base price to receive a commission of (3000*.08) + (1900*.4) to get 240+760=1000
I need an algebraic equation for this instance so that I could plug in the commission amount and get the price I need to charge.

I think you're looking for something like this; it takes into account the overall 24% limit on commissions:
base_price = 3000
base_comm_rate = 0.08
base_comm = base_price*base_comm_rate
excess_comm_rate = 0.4
comm_limit_rate = 0.24
target_comm = 1500

sale_price = max((target_comm-base_comm+(excess_comm_rate*base_price))/excess_comm_rate, target_comm/comm_limit_rate)
print(sale_price)

The output sale price results in an aggregate commission equal to 24%; if you change the target commission to $1,000 (as in your question) the sale price will be $4,900, which is $1,900 over the base price.

"never earn more than 24%" <-- does that mean the max should be a min?

@wsdookadr I know it's counterintuitive, but because of the fact that the limit commission is calculated off of the gross sales price while the non-limit on is calculated off of the spread (plus base commission) and you're trying to solve for the sale price - the sale price itself is the max, not the min! I struggled with this - but it's the right approach. Try running some examples - an interesting mental exercise.

guys ill look at this tonight when i get off work. I appreciate all the input.  ill have time then to run some test cases.  New job, if I dont get this right it could really burn me so I want to make sure I have a reliable equation I can run on the go without taking a half hour to figure it out. Thanks
